# Is it required to use orElse(null) in Streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I used this code snippet to find the first item in the String List which contained `'o'` character :

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("hi", "hello", "bye", "goodbye");
String s1 = words.stream().filter(word -> word.contains("o")).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

So this finds the first item that has `'o'` (hello) and if it doesn't find anything it will return `null` as specified by `orElse(null)`. So my question is :

**Is it really necessary to use `orElse(null)` and if I don't specify it what will it return as default if it doesn't find any matches?**

Comment: Did you try it without `orElse`?

Comment: As I removed it, it complains that Optional and String are incompatiable

Comment: here in list `hello` is at second , what is your output for `hi`?

Comment: findFirst returns an Optional. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

Comment: you need to `collect` it

Comment: @AsteriskNinja, I guess `collect` converts `stream` to `List`, am I right? ( correct me if I'm wrong )

Comment: **NOTE**  `filter` wont pass any word that does not contains `o`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`findFirst` returns an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). You need to use one of the `orElse` methods to get an actual value from it.

Comment: Didn't know about `Optional`, interesting stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, `findFirst()` returns an `Optional<String>`. The Optional has the advantage to avoid null checks and gives the opportunity to define a default value with `orElse("deafault")`. To write `orElse(null)` is in absolutely counterproductive!

Comment: Thanks for the alerting me about `orElse(null)` not being constructive.